# how to send form data in orchard CMS

Tags: asp.net, orchardcms, asp.net-mail

I'm using a form in my orchard website. How i can sent the form data to an email 
     address?
     My form is like

```
   <form>
       <input type="text" name="name">
       <input type="submit"name="submit" value="submit">
     </form>
```

Comment: Are you posting the form to your own controller?

Comment: Actually I'm new to this cms. Don't have much knowledge in .net , I just added this form in Layout.cshtml file

Answer (score 1):

Orchard has built-in ways to do this. If you enable the `Dynamic Forms`, `Email Messaging` and `Email Workflows Activities` modules you can build forms and send emails with the submitted values, without writing a single line of code.

When you enable the `Email Messaging` module you will be prompted to configure the email settings. The only mandatory settings are *Sender email address* and *host name*. You can enter any email address here and use *localhost* for testing purposes.

If you want to show the form on every page, you don't need to edit the `Layout.cshtml` file. In fact there's rarely a reason to do so. Instead, go to the Widgets menu in the dashboard and add a new **Form Widget** to the default layer. Which *zone* you place it in is entirely up to you. In the editor of the widget you can build a form by dragging *Dynamic Form elements* to the layout.

Once you have your form set up, you can create a new workflow through the Workflows menu that sends an email every time your form is submitted. Simply start off with a `Dynamic Form Submitted` trigger to begin the workflow and link it to a `Send Email` activity. You can reference the form values in any of the email fields by using tokens, e.g.:

```
<div>Name: {FormSubmission.Field:Name}</div>
```

You can find step by step guides on dynamic forms and workflows in the official documentation:
http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Creating-Dynamic-Forms/
http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Workflows/

Just ignore the part on *Custom Forms* when you get to Workflows, since those are outdated.